Show that $\frac{2}{9} \leq \frac{\tan(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})}{\sqrt{5}} \leq \frac{2}{5}$
I have to show that $\frac{2}{9} \leq \int^1_{-1} \frac{1}{x^2+2x+6}dx \leq \frac{2}{5}$ .
$\int^1_{-1} \frac{1}{x^2+2x+6}dx= \int^1_{-1} \frac{1}{(x+1)^2+5}dx$
Substituting $u=x+1 , du=dx ,$ upper bound is $2$ lower bound is $0$
$\int^2_{0} \frac{1}{u^2+5}du = \frac{1}{5}\int^2_{0} \frac{1}{\frac{u^2}{5}+1}du$
Substituting $t= \frac{u}{\sqrt{5}}, dt=\frac{du}{\sqrt{5}}$ upper bound becomes $2 \over \sqrt{5}$ and lower bound $0$
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\int^{2/ \sqrt{5}}_{0} \frac{1}{t^2+1}dt$
Then let $t=\tan(ω), dt=\tan^2(ω)+1$ upper bound $\tan(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})$ and lower $0$
So finally
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \int^{\tan(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})}_0 \frac{\tan^2(ω)+1}{\tan^2(ω)+1} dω = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \int^{\tan(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})}_0dω$
applying the fundamental theorem of calculus we get
$\frac{\tan(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})}{\sqrt{5}}$
But how can I show that $\frac{2}{9} \leq \frac{\tan(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})}{\sqrt{5}} \leq \frac{2}{5}$
Any help would be appreciated , Thanks in advance .
EDIT:
I made a mistake
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\int^{2/ \sqrt{5}}_{0} \frac{1}{t^2+1}dt = \frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})}{\sqrt{5}}$
Which makes more sense since $\frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})}{\sqrt{5}}=0.32 \dots \in[\frac{2}{9}, \frac{2}{5}]$

When you change variables with $t = \tan(\omega)$ the upper bound of the integral should actually become $\arctan^{-1}(2/\sqrt{5})$

@MattWerenski Thanks for pointing it out I edited the original post and added the correct version at the end.

I'm guessing you need to show instead $\frac29 < \arctan(2/\sqrt 5)/\sqrt 5 < \frac 25$

The inequality is false, since $x<\tan(x)$ for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$ and so $$\tan(2/\sqrt{5})>\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\implies \dfrac{\tan(2/\sqrt{5})}{\sqrt{5}}>\dfrac{2}{5}$$
To prove the original bounds, just notice that, if $x\in (-1,1)$, $$5\leq(x+1)^2+5=x^2+2x+6\leq 9,$$
so we immediately get $$\dfrac{2}{9}=\int^1_{-1}\frac{1}{9} dx \leq \int^1_{-1} \frac{1}{x^2+2x+6}dx \leq \int^1_{-1}\frac{1}{5} dx=\dfrac{2}{5}$$

That is much simpler than I originally thought . Thank you !
